# Can you make an equation out of a set builder notation expression?

Tags: notation

Would I be able to make an equation based on the following provided information?

{(x,x^2) | x is a real number}

Comment: There are all sorts of equations you could make.  What do you want the equation to say?

Comment: What do you mean by "make an equation out of a set"?  Something like: $$S=\{(x,x^2):x\in\Bbb R\}\\\qquad\Updownarrow\\\forall x~( x\in\Bbb R\gets\hspace{-2ex}\to(x,x^2)\in S)$$